# Unit tests coverage using Jacoco for test classes written using Powermock

Tags: java, maven, junit, powermock, jacoco

I am trying to get the code coverage report on the sonarqube dashboard on jenkins. The code coverage report is coming up but showing only 4.6% coverage. On investigating I found out that the test classes written using PowerMocks are getting skipped.

On further investigation I found that "JaCoCo doesn't play well with dynamically modified/created classes (this is the way how powermock works). This is a known limitation we can't currently do anything about".

Is there any work around for this so that I can get proper code coverage for test classes written using PowerMocks too.

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow. The question you have posted does not fall in the scope of questions discussed here. Please refer to the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) to see what kind of questions you can ask here. Regards.

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer: no, there isn't.

Long answer - boils down to these options:

- have look into this Wiki [page](https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/Code-coverage-with-JaCoCo) by the PowerMock team - maybe maybe "offline instrumentation" works out for you.
- hope that the corresponding [bug](https://github.com/powermock/powermock/issues/422) gets fixed at some point (I wouldn't hold my breath on that)
- get rid of your dependency to PowerMock(ito) - by refactoring and improving your production code
- [ I *think* I evaluated various coverage tools long time ago; and there was one commercial one that claims to work even with PowerMock. But I don't recall any specifics. So I am basically saying: there *might* be a minuscule chance that another, proprietary coverage tool works with PowerMock ]

Comment: In case of JaCoCo there is an option to use offline instrumentation - see https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/Code-coverage-with-JaCoCo , however you right that even if EclEmma is based on JaCoCo, as of today there is no way to use offline instrumentation in EclEmma.

Comment: I added your link to my answer; thanks for the input!

Comment: Can offline instrumentation be used for getting code coverage with jacoco on jenkins too?

Comment: @Manas You shouldn't expect us to give complete, fully ready to "digest" solutions. Answering that question might simply include spending some time to finding out. Of course, if somebody can give a clear "no, it will not work", that might save you some time. But in the end: it is your project, so you should probably just see how far this advice gets you.

Comment: I just followed the example and updated my pom accordingly. It still shows 4.6% code coverage so it didn't work for me, hence i asked this question.

Comment: Sounds like you got your answer ;-(

Comment: @Manas in this case please add **minimal complete and verifiable example** (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) into your question, e.g. class and its test, because example at https://github.com/powermock/powermock-examples-maven/tree/master/jacoco-offline works just perfectly with or without Jenkins.

Comment: Note: you can always upvote other answers from user in case you want to show your appreciation to them. For here, consider if the content of my answer is good enough to accept the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I have managed to generate PowerMock coverage with Jacoco, using `powermock-module-javaagent`.

Just make sure you put powermock agent **after** jacoco agent:

```
<artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <useSystemClassLoader>true</useSystemClassLoader>
                <argLine>${jacocoArgLine} -javaagent:${settings.localRepository}/org/powermock/powermock-module-javaagent/${powermock.version}/powermock-module-javaagent-${powermock.version}.jar -noverify</argLine>
...
```

If you want to see an example, take a look at this project: https://github.com/jfcorugedo/sonar-scanner

Here you can see that sonar takes into account static methods and `new` statements mocked by PowerMock:

[image]

If you want to mock `new`statements make sure you use `PowerMockRule` instead of `PowerMockRunner`.

Take a look at [this test](https://github.com/jfcorugedo/sonar-scanner/blob/master/src/test/java/es/jfcorugedo/CalculatorConstructorTest.java)

Comment: It appears that you didn't have to use JaCoCo's offline instrumentation to get this working...is that true?  Are you still using JaCoCo's online instrumentation here?

Comment: Yes, it’s true. Using the configuration I gave you in the sample project all the coverage is measured using both Jacoco and PowerMock agents

Comment: I'm extremely excited about the possibility of this working.  However, I used the pom from your sample project as an example and have not had any success yet.  Basically all of my unit tests are now failing with various errors, many of which appear in this form:  `java.lang.VerifyError: Expecting a stackmap frame at branch target 49
Exception Details:
    com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper{much more here}
  Reason:
    Expected stackmap frame at this location.
  Bytecode:
    0x0000000: 8a2a bb00 8c59 1040{much more here}`
I have included the PM Runner and Agent fwiw.

Comment: I was wrong!  I can't get the Eclipse Coverage Configuration to work (just yet), but that's candy.  When I actually just run `mvn clean install` it works wonderfully.  This is huge actually - I feel like you should post over on the Github PowerMock page about this if you haven't already!

Comment: Interesting. Can you share your code to let me take a look? Are you using JUnit 5? I had some problems with JUnit 5, but after changing it with JUnit 4 everything worked.

Comment: @risingTide great! Happy to help you with this. BTW it is a good idea to leave a comment on the PowerMock github repo.

Comment: Hi @jfcorugedo I have downloaded your git code and when I am running as maven test I am getting below error:                                                                                                                       Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class jdk.internal.reflect.ConstructorAccessorImpl loaded by org.powermock.core.classloader.MockClassLoader cannot access jdk/internal/reflect superclass jdk.internal.reflect.MagicAccessorImpl

Answer (score 0):

What works for me is to remove this

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
```

And add this in the class

```
@Rule
public PowerMockRule rule = new PowerMockRule();
```

Also need to add the dependency for powermockito junit4 rule.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
  <artifactId>powermock-module-junit4-rule</artifactId>
  <version>2.0.2</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

This [official page](https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/PowerMockRule) will help more to understand it. [PowerMock](https://powermock.github.io/)